# Create non-capturing method reference which will call superclass method

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I'm trying to refactor the following code:

```
class Base {
  private Object a, b, <...>; // there's like 10 of these attributes of different type

  public Object a() {
    return a;
  }
  public Object b() {
    return b;
  }
  // more getters like the ones above
}

class RootNode extends Base { }

class BranchNode extends Base {
  private RootNode root; // passed via constructor

  public Object a() {
    Object value = super.a();
    return value != null ? value : root.a();
  }
  public Object b() {
    Object value = super.b();
    return value != null ? value : root.b();
  }
  // below are more methods like the above one, all with same logic
}
```

Naturally, I want to remove the repetition in this code to save myself from typing even more of the same lines when new properties are added, but I cannot quite figure out how to do that.

My first instinct was that it looks a lot like this code (which, unfortunately, does not compile):

```
private <T> T nvlGet(Function<Base, T> accessor) {
  T value = accessor.apply(super); // this is the problem line, because there is no way to pass a "super-reference" to anything
  return value != null ? value : accessor.apply(root);
}

// and then public accessors would look like this:
public Object a() {
  return nvlGet(Base::a);
}
```

I can't obviously "fix" the above code by calling `accessor.apply(this)` instead of `accessor.apply(super)`, because that would cause a `Stack Overflow` error.

Closest I managed to come up with so far is using bound suppliers, like this:

```
private <T> T nvlGet(Supplier<T> first, Supplier<T> second) {
  T value = first.get();
  return value != null ? value : second.get();
}
public Object a() {
  return nvlGet(super::a, root::a);
}
```

However, that is two times as many references to same method than I'd like to have in ideal world. So, I would like to know if I'm missing something, and I can still somehow fix the version which uses `Function<Base, T>`

Comment: Can't you use some protected getters for the objects and use them in your public getters?

Comment: @KDM, I don't really see how making anything protected solves this problem, really. I suppose I could have a protected `getA` which would allow me to create `Base::getA` where I can then pass a `this`, but that in turn creates two times as many getter methods as I had before: public ones which use site will call, and protected ones which are used to avoid stack looping. I'm not sure if going this route is worth it though.

Comment: Something like your first solution is not going to work, since `Base::a` encapsulates an `invokevirtual` and `super::a` an `invokespecial`, that is not going to change based on what you pass it. You need both, which is what your second solution does.

Comment: @JornVernee, I see. So the `Supplier` version I have come up with is the best I can do for now?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, that one looks pretty clean to me.

Comment: @Michael, I don't understand your comment. Third party doesn't have a say in which implementation is selected, `BranchNode` always behaves like this. These two classes are part of configuration definition, where in tree-like structure an option can be overridden at some level, and if not, it comes from higher up configuration. The only thing different from my actual code is that `Branch` has a parent of type `Root` here, whereas in actual code it has parent of type `Base`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov True. Okay, the reason it is so ugly is because you have nullable methods. Return `Optional`s.

Comment: @Michael, until Java9 and its `or()` methods, I can't "recover" with another optional. We will not be moving to Java 9 this release as well, and until that I'd argue that using Optional<T> as return value will make it more ugly, not less. There's also the fact that we'll be supposed to have default values at root, even if no one has set anything there.

Comment: Unrelated: *@GhostCat, Jython is a way of running Python on JVM, but I'm guessing he's trying to do the opposite.* That really depends on context. Jython is an elegant way to combine both worlds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “super reference” that would alter the outcome of an ordinary invocation of an overridable method (aka `invokevirtual` instruction).

Your solution using two method references is the best you can get, as long as you insist on using functions, whereas passing evaluated values is even simpler:

```
private <T> T nvlGet(T value, Supplier<T> second) {
  return value != null? value: second.get();
}
public Object a() {
  return nvlGet(super.a(), root::a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As said by others, you can't do much better, because `super` is not a reference you can pass around.

I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504251/1876620) in that passing the values returned by the `super.a()`, `super.b()`, etc invocations is simpler.

In addition, I would change the 2nd argument to be of type `Function<? super Base, ? extends T>`, so that the usage of the `root` instance in the `nvlGet` method remains encapsulated:

```
private <T> T nvlGet(T nullable, Function<? super Base, ? extends T> second) {
    return nullable != null ? nullable : second.apply(root);
}
```

Usage:

```
public Object a() {
    return nvlGet(super.a(), Base::a);
}

public Object b() {
    return nvlGet(super.b(), Base::b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use a **dynamic proxy class** that allows dynamic handling; implementing an interface using reflection. However it is not as costly as pure reflection.

But first consider an alternative: using `Optional<A> a()` as that certainly is less artificial, less baroque.

Use an interface and create an [InvocationHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html):

```
interface Abc {
    public A a();
    public B b();
}

public Class AbcProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Object obj;

    public AbcProxy(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            ...
            return ...;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is maybe not very intuitive, and having just `a()`, `b()`, I cannot make sensible sample code. So perhaps better start with example code.

Comment: IIUC, using or not using a proxy here is just an implementation detail, I would then store my values in a `HashMap` and only call `m` with passing a parent node to it, and only if map doesn't contain my value. So in the end, what would I actually gain from this indirection? As for Optional, using it is valid suggestion, but it isn't really relevant (and until we migrate to 9, I would sorely miss `or()` method).

Comment: A proxy would be better than using accessors w.r.t. performance. It is almost made for such a _delegation pattern_. But I hesitate too, which shows in the answer I hope. About `Optional` we seem to be on the same wavelength. In fact the original ugly code might be the best, the most pragmatic.